# UITableViewCell's height different on iOS 8 (compared to iOS 7)

Tags: ios, uitableview

Something is troubling me. I have a `UITableView` with cells that contain images. When using the iOS 7 simulator, the images gets constrained to the cell's height. When I tested it on the iOS 8 simulator, the cell expanded to the height of the image, and it is kinda buggy. Buggy because the height may change back to the height which appeared under iOS 7. Can someone kindly enlighten me please =D

My app is built using iOS 7 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all I can do for now is to use this:

`self.tableView.rowHeight = 44.0;`

Do let me know if any of you geniuses out there got something better =D